# colourthief.getColorFromUrl error on chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, microsoft-edge, color-thief

I am using this GitHub project: github.com/lokesh/color-thief

The aim is to get the overall colour of an image stored internally on the server and set it as the background.

I created this test page to show the problem:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>TEST</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="post.css" media="screen" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/color-thief.js"></script>
  <script src="js/quantize.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>

  <div id="samedomain">
    <img src="memes/apple.jpg" width="400" height="400">
    <h1>Same domain, image by url</h1>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    var colorThief = new ColorThief();
      colorSync = colorThief.getColorFromUrl("memes/apple.jpg", function(color){
      $('#samedomain').css('background-color','rgb('+color[0]+','+color[1]+','+color[2]+')')
      console.log('url',color)
    });
  </script>

</head>

<body>
  <p id="bob">...</p>
</body>

</html>
```

The website runs great on Edge presenting the image and corresponding background.
[edge result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nr0gc.png)

When i ran it in Chrome it didn't display the background, but instead an additional copy of the image.
[chrome result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fScqt.png)

I got the error

> Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'getImageData' on
>   'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The canvas has been tainted by
>   cross-origin data.
>       at CanvasImage.getImageData (file:///C:/Users/?/Desktop/sites/roller/js/color-thief.js:52:25)
>       at ColorThief.getPalette (file:///C:/Users/?/Desktop/sites/roller/js/color-thief.js:110:28)
>       at HTMLImageElement. (file:///C:/Users/?/Desktop/sites/roller/js/color-thief.js:145:29)

How can i solve this problem for chrome?

Comment: Chrome treats all file URLs as cross domain even if they are relative (file:///xyz/stuff).You need to access page by`http://` or `https://` by using a server

Comment: So I'll just have to use edge for development purposes and when I upload it onto the server it will work fine.